# How to open an url as a website with request python?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I am trying to make a google map direction system with user accounts. However, I don't know how to open a url on a web browser with python. I know there is webbrowser.open() but my code contains a view.py request which needs the username and password to pass through POST in order to access the user information.

This is my view.py file

```
def maps(request):
    username = password = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:

                login(request, user)

                traffic_start = Auth.objects.get(user = user).traffic_start
                traffic_end = Auth.objects.get(user = user).traffic_end
                print traffic_start


    return render_to_response('maps.html', {'start':traffic_start, 'end': traffic_end})
```

And I am trying to open "localhost:8000/maps" with the request info after dismissing my GUI.

I know about urllib, urllib2, and webbrowser, but none of those seem to satisfy what I want to do, please help!!

Comment: Not understanding the question. What do you mean open a URL on browser? Do you want to redirect? Are you calling an API and getting data to show on ur page?

Comment: So I have a local GUI which requires the users to log on with their username and pw. After they log on, they have the option to click the map button which ideally will pop out a new web page (map.html) and automatically display the directions of their default start and end points. I have the GUI, html, and view.py files ready, but I don't know how to make the pop out happen.

Comment: If I understand correctly, user should click on a link and then it should open a popup? So basically put `target=_blank` for your `a` tag. Check here for more info:

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: No, the user will click on a button of a local GUI, then it opens a popup website

Comment: to clear it up even more, i'm trying to do webbrowser.open() with request, like username and password passed in